# Display Comments from Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, api

I've got a public page on Facebook where people can post comments and I want to list all my page comments in a C# application.

I found this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

But it doesn't work, for exemple: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.facebook.com/Diablo returns 1 comment but there are more than 5xxxx comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments plugin is for Open Graph pages outside of the main Facebook site. You cannot use the plugin for your Facebook fan page.

Consider using the `PAGE_ID/feed` connection see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#feed for more information

Answer (score 0):

try: `https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids={YOUR PAGE URL}`
make sure you anter a full url